# Bower jquery Installation failing

Tags: jquery, node.js, bower

On my project while I'm trying to install bower install jquery after some time its shows the following error. But for bootstrap it worked perfectly. The error is

> Resource Busy of locked

```
bower install popper.js --save
bower                     invalid-meta for:C:\Users\asm morshed\Desktop\webTest\bower.json
bower                     invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes
bower popper.js#*           not-cached https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js.git#*
bower popper.js#*              resolve https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js.git#*
bower popper.js#*             download https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/archive/v1.14.3.tar.gz
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\ASMMOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\DESKTOP-9Q2LRB9-asm morshed\bower\3ced9414d81149364fae3ce47bc0d427-3756-zLrkYS\archive.tar.gz.2593295678' -> 'C:\Users\ASMMOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\DESKTOP-9Q2LRB9-asm morshed\bower\3ced9414d81149364fae3ce47bc0d427-3756-zLrkYS\archive.tar.gz'
```

actually I can't udenstand what is happening there. Please help me to find out the error. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try starting the command with sudo?

Comment: no. I'm just starting with bower install jquery.I'm using windows 10 and for writing command I'm using Cmder command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Bower is trying to rename an archive file it downloaded, but the file is used by another process as well.
Sometimes it's an Explorer or cli window you need to close. 
I used to get such errors quite often and sometimes the only option to find and kill the process in question is to restart the system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually right now it is working for me after uninstalling "Reason Core Security". I just write it on my command line
C:\Program Files\Reason\Security\uninstall.exe
and afte restarting my pc finally it's done.